# Parent constructor + Object.create(Parent.prototype) vs new Parent()?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype

Are `D1`, `D2`(and by extension, `d1`, `d2`) equivalent? What are the notable differences between them, if any?

Also, how should I go about making the prototypes of `D1` and `D2` unmodifiable via `Base.prototype`? Such that neither gets `baz` as shown.

```
var d1, d2
function Base() {this.foo = 'foo'}
Base.prototype.bar = 'bar'

function D1() { }
D1.prototype = new Base()

function D2() {Base.call(this)}
D2.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype)

Base.prototype.baz = 'baz'

d1 = new D1()
d2 = new D2()

console.log(d1.foo, d1.bar, d1.baz)
//-> foo bar baz
console.log(d2.foo, d2.bar, d2.baz)
//-> foo bar baz
```

Comment: No, [they're not equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here), check *where* `.foo` is created. And why would you make them "unmodifiable", isn't that the whole point of inheritance to reflect such changes?